# Magento 2 - Product names with number/digits & special characters are not searchable

Tags: magento2, product, search, catalogsearch, fulltext

I have product names like ' 8" X 6" cards ' they contain measurements i.e. numbers and characters. when I try to search these products on the frontend. the Ajax search returns the product fine and product with that name is displayed in the dropdown but when I try to search it with MYSQL search gives "Your search returned no results.". Is there a way to make products with these type of names searchable ?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? please let me know if you solve we are also facing this same issues